# Auto start pgAgent

Tags: postgresql, windows-server, pgagent

When my `windows server 2008` start, both services `postgres` and `pgAgent` start because they are automatic.

[image]

But if my db is frozen and I need to restart the `postgres` service, the `pgAgent` is also stoped, but when `postgres` restart, `pgAgent` doesn't. So I have to restart `pgAgent` manually.

Is there a way to link `pgAgent`, so that it starts whenever `postgresql` starts?

PD: If someone knows a proper tag for windows services please add it, I couldn't find it.

Comment: Searching "win start multi services". I am using batch file instead of using service. From the question above, batch file contains : line 1: pg_ctl.exe  start -D  line 2: your_data & pgagent.exe ......

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try a different job agent rather than PGAgent, I wrote an alternative that takes care of this issue.  It will stay running once your database goes down, and reconnect once it comes back up.

It's called jpgAgent: https://github.com/Tostino/jpgAgent

It also has quite a few more features, and has been much more stable for me over the past few months I've been using it in production.

Any questions, feel free to ask.

-Adam